# Specifying plane waves

Tags: physics

I'm having trouble understanding how to specify a transverse wave (including it's longitudinal axis *and* transverse direction) in 3d space.

I know this is called a "plane wave", and I know the formula for a plane wave along a unit vector $\hat{k}$ is:

$$
A( \vec{r}, t ) = A_0 cos( \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t + \phi )
$$

Which is from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave)

Where $\vec{k}$ is the longitudinal axis and $\vec{r}$ is the space position.  The output of this function should be the magnitude of the wave at that point in space.

But I don't understand where you specify the transverse axis.  From this picture it appears that the wave described must be a longitudinal wave with only one axis, modelling something like compressions and rarefactions in air.

[image: wave]

What is the transverse axis here?  How do you specify a transverse axis?

I want a single wave that looks like *just* either the red one or the blue one [from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation):

[image: em wave]

I can't see where the transverse axis comes in or how you specify it's direction.

Comment: Well, you just pick the direction of the transverse axis, say $\vec u$, and let your wave be $\vec u A_0 \cos( \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t + \phi )$... Of course, that can only describe a linearly polarized wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Longitudinal waves are along the direction of propagation, e.g., along the $y$-direction in your second figure.

Transverse waves are not longitudinal---the displacement is perpendicular to the direction of propagation, e.g., in the $x$- or $z$-direction in your figure. 
These two types of transverse waves are in independent states of polarization.
They can be combined to form linearly, circularly, or elliptically polarized waves.

A transverse wave in the $x$-$y$ plane (blue in the figure) is described by 
$A_x \cos(k y - \omega t) \hat x$. 
A general transverse wave propagating in the $y$-direction would look like
$$A_x \cos(k y - \omega t)\hat x 
+ A_z \cos(k y - \omega t + \phi)\hat z,$$
where $A_x,A_z \ge0$ and $-\pi < \phi \le \pi$.

1. If $\phi = 0$ or $\pi$ the wave is said to be linearly polarized.
2. If $A_x = A_z$ and $\phi = \pm \pi/2$ the wave is circularly polarized.
   (The circular polarization is left- or right-handed depending on the sign of $\phi$ and your convention for handedness.)
3. Otherwise the wave is elliptically polarized.

---

*Addendum*: 
To describe a transverse wave propagating with wave vector ${\bf k}$ we must first find a unit vector orthogonal to ${\bf k}$, call it $\hat n$.
This is one of the transverse directions. 
The other can be chosen to be $\hat k\times \hat n$.
(It's a good exercise to show this is a unit vector orthogonal to $\hat k$ and $\hat n$.)
Then a general transverse wave will be represented by 
$$A \cos({\bf k}\cdot {\bf r} - \omega t)\hat n
+ B \cos({\bf k}\cdot {\bf r} - \omega t + \phi)\hat k\times \hat n,$$
where $A,B \ge0$ and $-\pi < \phi \le \pi$.
Replace $A_x,A_y$ with $A,B$ above to determine the type of polarization.

For example, if we want a linearly polarized wave propagating along the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,1)$ direction with polarization vector $\hat y = (0,1,0)$ we will find the wave described by
$$A \cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}k(x+z) - \omega t\right) \hat y.$$
(Note that 
${\bf k}\cdot {\bf r} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}k(x+z)$.)

Comment: But what about sending the transverse wave in an arbitrary direction?  Say we want to define a transverse wave in 3d space that has longitidinal axis $ ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ) $, and with transverse axis $(0,1,0)$.  How would you define it?

Comment: @bobobobo: Added.

Answer (score 0):

Every part of a plane wave which is not longitudinal to the direction of propagatin is transverse. So if you have $\vec{k}$ being the direction of propagation and unit vectors $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$ with $\vec{E}$ as your wave vector, then your transverse components are $\hat{u}\cdot \vec{E}$ and $\hat{v}\cdot \vec{E}$ and $\hat{u}\cdot \hat{v}=0, \hat{u}\cdot \vec{k}=0, \hat{v}\cdot \vec{k}=0$.

There's a common way of representing plane waves representing a vector:

$$\vec{E}=\sum_i^\infty=\vec{a_i}e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}-wt)}$$

This allows Fourier Analysis to determine your $\vec{a_i}$.

You can restrict yourself to the real part for both transverse components. The imaginary part contains seldom important phase information.

You want $\sum_i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{a_i}=0$ to guarantee no longitudinal components.

An alternative way to express this condition is forcing $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=0\implies \vec{E}=\nabla \times\vec{A}$ for some $\vec{A}.$

Often $\vec{A}=\hat{k}\Psi(\vec{r})e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}-wt)}$ suffices.